# Raspberry pi project to read temperature, can i create an android application which helps me in getting the temperature from raspberry pi !?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi

I have made a raspberry pi project, where i have used python code to read temperature and according to certain variations in temperatures a message is sent to concerned user.
Can i create an android application which helps me in getting the temperature from raspberry pi and make changes in python code where i can change phone numbers of the users.

Comment: Yes, you can.  As long as you are not monitoring the temps of a nuclear reactor in the south eastern US.

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach would be to create Rest services on the Pi and then query those from the mobile devices.  I've done something similar in the past with Java, you can take a look at that [project](https://code.google.com/p/stoker-web/) for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Of course and probably in 20 different ways minimum.

Comment: Can u plz share me some links that will help me.